# NHibernate session management

Tags: nhibernate, session

I use NHiberante at my win service. Sometimes I get

```
System.ObjectDisposedException: Session is closed!
Object name: 'ISession'.
   at NHibernate.Impl.AbstractSessionImpl.ErrorIfClosed()
   at NHibernate.Impl.AbstractSessionImpl.CheckAndUpdateSessionStatus()
   at NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl.FireSave(SaveOrUpdateEvent event)
   at NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl.Save(Object obj)
   at Attraction.DAL.Repositories.Repository`1.Save(T entity)
   at Attraction.VideoDispatcher.Program.ThreadPoolCallback(Object threadContext)
```

I have no idea what's wrong.
My session management subsystem:

Repository:

```
 public class Repository<T> : IRepository<T>, IDisposable
    {
        protected readonly bool CommitAtDispose;
        public Repository(bool commitAtDispose)
        {
            CommitAtDispose = commitAtDispose;
            StartSession();
        }
        private void StartSession()
        {
            if (NHibernateSession == null)
                NHibernateHelper.StartSession();
        }
        public void Dispose()
        {
            if (CommitAtDispose)
                Flush();
        }
        public void Flush()
        {
            NHibernateHelper.EndSession();
        }
        protected override sealed ISession NHibernateSession
        {
            get
            {
                return SessionManager.CurrentSession; 
            }
        }       
        public virtual T GetById(int id)       
        public virtual List<T> GetAll()        
        public virtual List<T> GetByPage(int pageIndex, int pageSize)       
        public virtual int GetCount()        
        public virtual List<T> GetByCriteria(params ICriterion[] criterion)       
        public virtual T Save(T entity)       
        public virtual T Update(T entity)        
        public virtual void Delete(T entity)        
    }
}
```

SessionManager - singletone for provide access to sessionfactory

```
public class SessionManager : ISessionFactoryProvider
{
        private static readonly ILog Log = LogManager.GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);
        private readonly ISessionFactory sessionFactory;
        public static ISessionFactory SessionFactory
        {
            get { return Instance.sessionFactory; }
        }
        public ISessionFactory GetSessionFactory()
        {
            return sessionFactory;
        }
        public static ISession OpenSession()
        {
            return Instance.GetSessionFactory().OpenSession();
        }
        public static ISession CurrentSession
        {
            get
            {
                if (!CurrentSessionContext.HasBind(Instance.GetSessionFactory()))
                    return null;
                return Instance.GetSessionFactory().GetCurrentSession();
            }
        }


        public static SessionManager Instance
        {
            get
            {
                return NestedSessionManager.sessionManager;
            }
        }
        private SessionManager()
        {
            Log.Info("Start creating factory");
            Configuration configuration = new Configuration().Configure();
            sessionFactory = configuration.BuildSessionFactory();
            Log.Info("End creating factory");

        }

        class NestedSessionManager
        {
            internal static readonly SessionManager sessionManager =
                new SessionManager();
        }
    }
```

NhibernateHelper, which do some work for start and end session:

```
public static class NHibernateHelper
    {
        public static void StartSession()
        {
            var session = SessionManager.SessionFactory.OpenSession();
            session.BeginTransaction();
            CurrentSessionContext.Bind(session);

        }
        public static void EndSession()
        {
            var session = SessionManager.CurrentSession;
            CurrentSessionContext.Unbind(SessionManager.SessionFactory);
            if (session != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    if (session.Transaction != null && session.Transaction.IsActive)
                        session.Transaction.Commit();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    session.Transaction.Rollback();
                    throw new ApplicationException("Error committing database transaction. "+ex.Message, ex);
                }
                finally
                {
                    session.Close();
                    session.Dispose();

                }
            }


        }
    }
```

May be my design isn't so good, but I couldn't imagine how can I catch this error.

**UPD**

Sorry my config. I haven't migrate to fluent yet so:

```
<hibernate-configuration xmlns="urn:nhibernate-configuration-2.2">
    <session-factory>
      <property name="connection.provider">NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider</property>
      <property name="dialect">NHibernate.Dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
      <property name="connection.driver_class">NHibernate.Driver.MySqlDataDriver</property>
      <property name="connection.connection_string">***</property>
      <property name="show_sql">false</property>
      <property name="default_schema">**_***</property>
      <property name="current_session_context_class">thread_static</property>
      <mapping assembly="***.Core"/>
    </session-factory>
  </hibernate-configuration>
```

**UPD2**

Save method:

```
        public virtual T Save(T entity)
        {
            NHibernateSession.Save(entity);
            return entity;
        }
```

Threadpool callback:

```
        public static void DetectStart(Object threadContext)
        {
            try
            {
                var task = (TasksPerAttraction)threadContext;                
                var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(..., ...)
                {
                    UseShellExecute = false,
                    RedirectStandardOutput = true
                };
                Process p = Process.Start(startInfo);
                var outputXml = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
                p.WaitForExit();
                var doc = XDocument.Parse(outputXml);
                foreach (var xElement in doc.Root.Descendants("start"))
                {
                    var startDetection = new StartDetection
                                             {
                                                 DtStart = DateTime.Parse(xElement.Attribute("startTime").Value),
                                                 Attraction = task.Attraction,                                                
                                             };
                    lock (spinLock)
                    {
                        using (var repo = new Repository<StartDetection>(true))
                            repo.Save(startDetection);
                    }
                }
                var tskRepo = new Repository<Task>(true);
                foreach(var tsk in task.Tasks)
                {
                    tsk.IsProcessedStart = true;
                    tskRepo.Update(tsk);
                }
                tskRepo.Flush();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //....
            }
        }
```

Comment: Can you post up your configuration, I think it is to do with which type of context you are using but I cant tell from what you have posted so far.

For a windows service it should be "thread_static"

See section 2.3
http://www.nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html

Comment: Can you show your code for Program.ThreadPoolCallback and Repository.Save?

Comment: A little off topic here, but I strongly suggest to get rid of the generic Repository. ISession already has all the semantics of a Repository- just use it directly. With the generic Repository you just uselessly put an abstraction layer on top of an abstraction layer. I had to learn this the hard way myself. See: http://blog.gauffin.org/2012/02/generic-repositories-a-silly-abstraction-layer/ and http://ayende.com/blog/4071/dont-castrate-your-architecture

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few potential issues, but I suspect the biggest issue is that you are saving the task.Attraction in one session (so the Attraction for that task is associated to session 1), and then saving the tasks in another session - so you end up with the Attraction in session 1, which is now closed, and session 2 is navigating the relationships to see if it needs to save the Attraction and hence the error.  This is a bit of an assumption since I don't have your model or mapping.

I think the easiest fix would be to open the session in your callback, ie:

```
public static void DetectStart(Object threadContext)
{
    try
    {
        ... run your process ...
        p.WaitForExit();
        // **** OPEN SESSION HERE ****
        NHibernateHelper.StartSession(); 

        var doc = XDocument.Parse(outputXml);
        foreach (var xElement in doc.Root.Descendants("start"))
        {
            var startDetection = new StartDetection
                                     {
                                         DtStart = DateTime.Parse(xElement.Attribute("startTime").Value),
                                         Attraction = task.Attraction,                                                
                                     };
            lock (spinLock)
            {
                // *** DON'T CLOSE THE SESSION ON DISPOSE
                using (var repo = new Repository<StartDetection>(false)) 
                    repo.Save(startDetection);
            }
        }
        // *** DON'T CLOSE THE SESSION ON DISPOSE HERE EITHER!
        using(var tskRepo = new Repository<Task>(false)) 
        { 
            foreach(var tsk in task.Tasks)
            {
                tsk.IsProcessedStart = true;
                tskRepo.Update(tsk);
            }
            tskRepo.Flush();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //....
    }
    finally {
        // *** MAKE SURE YOU CLOSE THE SESSION
        NHibernateHelper.EndSession();
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks! I know my session mngnt isn't perfect. I understand my error and try new variant. But what's the best strategy session mngmnt in desctop\console\winservice scenarios. I don't want issue ISession to code and would like incapsulate it at repository. So what should  repostory be for these goals?

Comment: Honestly, I've encapsulated the session in many different ways in lots of apps, and I've never found the encapsulation to be of any benefit, in fact it's always just overcomplicated things for no benefit at all.  I would suggest looking at http://nhforge.org/wikis/patternsandpractices/nhibernate-and-the-unit-of-work-pattern.aspx and just using the session without wrapping it in a repository

Answer (score 0):

Hello Andrew what if you use an IOC to deal with your session? I use ninject and It has been painless also I will share some code that may help you, this is my approximation to solve dealing with Nhibernate, but I am open to suggestions.

**The Repo Class:**

```
public class Repositorio<T> : IRepositorio<T> where T : class
{
    [Inject]
    public ISession Session { get; set; }

    #region IRepositorio<T> Members

    public IList<T> ListAll()
    {
        return Session.CreateCriteria<T>().List<T>();
    }

    public T Look(object id)
    {
        return Session.Get<T>(id);
    }

    public void Add(T t)
    {
        using (ITransaction transaction = Session.BeginTransaction())
        {
            transaction.Begin();
            try
            {
                Session.Save(t);
                transaction.Commit();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                transaction.Rollback();
                throw;
            }
            finally
            {
                transaction.Dispose();
            }

        }
    }

    public void Save(T t)
    {
        using (ITransaction transaction = Session.BeginTransaction())
        {
            transaction.Begin();
            try
            {
                Session.SaveOrUpdate(t);
                transaction.Commit();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                transaction.Rollback();
            }
            finally
            {
                transaction.Dispose();
            }

        }

    }

    public void Delete(T t)
    {
        using (ITransaction transaction = Session.BeginTransaction())
        {
            transaction.Begin();
            try
            {
                Session.Delete(t);
                transaction.Commit();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                transaction.Rollback();
                Console.WriteLine(e.StackTrace);
            }
            finally
            {
                transaction.Dispose();
            }

        }
    }

    #endregion

}
```

**My Nhibernate Helper:**

```
public sealed class NHibernateHelper
{
    public static ISessionFactory SessionFactory { get; set; }


    private static void OpenSession()
    {
        var configuration = new Configuration();
        configuration.Configure();
        SessionFactory = configuration.BuildSessionFactory();
    }


    public static ISession GetCurrentSession()
    {
        if (SessionFactory == null)
        {
            OpenSession();
        }
        if (SessionFactory != null)
            return SessionFactory.OpenSession();
        return null;
    }

    public static IStatelessSession GetStatelessSession()
    {
        if (SessionFactory == null)
        {
            OpenSession();
        }

        if (SessionFactory != null)
            return SessionFactory.OpenStatelessSession();
        return null;
    }

    public static void CloseSessionFactory()
    {
        if (SessionFactory != null)
            SessionFactory.Close();
    }
}
```

In my Module I do this:

**How do I Bind the session to a repo:**

```
Bind<ISession>().ToMethod(c => NHibernateHelper.GetCurrentSession()).InSingletonScope().OnDeactivation(c => NHibernateHelper.CloseSessionFactory());
```

Note: check the scope of the bind maybe for you is more appropriated the thread scope

**How do I bind the Open session with the repo**

```
Bind<SomeRepoImpl>().ToSelf();
```

hope that this help, I will be glad to help you.

Comment: Using a DI container for this is not generally a bad idea, but this a good example of how to do it wrong. When is the session ever closed in your example? What about thread safety? You do know that ISession (unlike ISessionFactory) is not thread safe, do you?
What I usually do is to inject the ISessionFactory with a DI container, but create and dispose sessions and transactions manually as needed.